# Passing data from recyclerview to details activity (kotlin, firebase)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm writing an app which allows you to set up a hairdresser appointment. I'm storing the data about the visits in firebase database. I'm trying to implement a recyclerview with onclick listener which displays date in recycler cardview and displays new activity with details after being clicked. I have a problem with passing data to this details activity. App crashes after recycler is clicked and the main error I get is

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing
> serializable object

What might be the reason?
This is how the database looks like:
[image: db screenshot]

OrderForm.class

```
package com.example.barberqueue.db

import com.example.barberqueue.SummaryViewModel
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.ArrayList

class OrderForm(
    val date: String? = null,
    val hour: String? = null,
    val isAccepted: Boolean = false,
    val isCanceled: Boolean = false,
    val isDone: Boolean = false,
    val price: Float = 0f,
    val services: ArrayList<SummaryViewModel>? = null,
    val servicesTime: Int = 0,
    val userId: String? = null
): Serializable {}
```

AppointmentsAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.barberqueue.adapters

import android.graphics.Color
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.barberqueue.R
import com.example.barberqueue.db.OrderForm
import com.example.barberqueue.interfaces.OrderClickView

class AppointmentsAdapter(
    private val appointmentsList: ArrayList<OrderForm>, private val orderClickView: OrderClickView

) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<AppointmentsAdapter.AppointmentsViewHolder>() {


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): AppointmentsViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.appointments_view_itemview,
            parent, false
        )
        return AppointmentsViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: AppointmentsViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = appointmentsList[position]

        holder.date.text = currentItem.date
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffffff"))
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {

            orderClickView.onClickOrder(appointmentsList[position], holder.bindingAdapterPosition)

        }
    }


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return appointmentsList.size
    }

    class AppointmentsViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val date: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.appointment_date)

    }
}
```

Dashboard.kt (where the recycler is displayed)

```
package com.example.barberqueue

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import com.example.barberqueue.adapters.AppointmentsAdapter
import com.example.barberqueue.databinding.DashboardBinding
import com.example.barberqueue.db.OrderForm
import com.example.barberqueue.interfaces.OrderClickView
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.ktx.auth
import com.google.firebase.database.*
import com.google.firebase.ktx.Firebase


class Dashboard : AppCompatActivity(), OrderClickView {
    private var x1: Float = 0F
    private var y1: Float = 0F
    private var x2: Float = 0F
    private var y2: Float = 0F
    private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var orderArrayList: ArrayList<OrderForm>
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    private lateinit var binding: DashboardBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_new_visit_btn)
        binding.addNewVisitBtn.setOnClickListener { openActivityNewVisit() }



        binding.accMngBtn.setOnClickListener { openActivityAccountManagement() }
        binding.logoutBtn.setOnClickListener {
            Firebase.auth.signOut()
            finish()
            openActivityMainActivity()
        }
        binding.logo.setOnClickListener {
            openActivityContact()
        }


        binding.appointmentsView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.appointmentsView.setHasFixedSize(true)

        orderArrayList = arrayListOf<OrderForm>()

        getData()


    }

    override fun onClickOrder(order: OrderForm, position: Int) {

        val intent= Intent(this, ViewAppointment::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("order", order)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun getData() {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("FutureAppointment")
        database.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    //Log.w("TAG", "app_added1")
                    for (appointmentSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val appointment = appointmentSnapshot.getValue(OrderForm::class.java)
                        if (appointment != null) {
                            if (appointment.userId == auth.currentUser?.uid /*oraz data jest w przyszłości lub dzisiejsza*/) {
                                orderArrayList.add(appointment)
                                //Log.w("TAG", "app_added")
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    binding.appointmentsView.adapter = AppointmentsAdapter(orderArrayList, this@Dashboard)
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.w("TAG", "loadPost:onCancelled")
            }

        })
    }

    private fun openActivityMainActivity() {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun openActivityContact() {
        val intent = Intent(this, ContactData::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    private fun changingTabs(position: Int) {

        if (position == 0) {

        }
        if (position == 1) {

        }
    }

    //funkcja do poruszania sie po ui w poziomie
    override fun onTouchEvent(touchEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {

        when (touchEvent.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                x1 = touchEvent.x
                y1 = touchEvent.y

            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                x2 = touchEvent.x
                y2 = touchEvent.y
                if (x1 < x2 && y1 <= y2 + 100 && y1 >= y2 - 100) {
                    openActivityMenu()
                    Log.e("position", "$x1,$y1     $x2,$y2")
                } else if (x1 > x2 && y1 <= y2 + 100 && y1 >= y2 - 100) {
                    openActivitySTH()
                    Log.e("position", "$x1,$y1     $x2,$y2")
                }


            }
        }


        return false
    }


    private fun openActivityAccountManagement() {
        val intent = Intent(this, AccountManagement::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun openActivityMenu() {
        val intent = Intent(this, Menu::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun openActivitySTH() {
        val intent = Intent(this, Right::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun openActivityNewVisit() {
        val intent = Intent(this, NewVisit::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }


}
```

Interfaces.kt

```
package com.example.barberqueue.interfaces

import com.example.barberqueue.db.OrderForm
import com.google.firebase.firestore.auth.User


interface FromMakeAppointmentToSummary {
    fun getSelectedTime(time: String)
}

interface OrderClickView{
    fun onClickOrder(orderForm : OrderForm, position: Int)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see there is an ArrayList of SummaryViewModel, is SummaryViewModel serializable?

Also...
I would not recommend passing viewModels to activities, rather stick to passing classes containing data instead of methods and consuming the data in the next activity.